# If a function returns a value entered by a user, how can I use that value in another function without asking the user to input another value

Tags: python

```
def userChoice():
    print("Press 1 to send text message\n Press 2 to share file")
    action = int(input("Please what do you want to do ? "))
    return action


def useValue():
    value=userChoice() + 1
    print(value)

userChoice()
useValue()
```

""" I discovered the second function asks for User input again whereas I don't want that, instead I just need the value already given by the user in the first function """

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit more from a guide or tutorial than a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the result of `userChoice()` and pass it in to `useValue()` as an argument. Try this:

```
def userChoice():
    print("Press 1 to send text message\n Press 2 to share file")
    action = int(input("Please what do you want to do ? "))
    return action


def useValue(choice):
    value=choice + 1
    print(value)

user_input = userChoice()
useValue(user_input)
```

The way you have it, the first call to `userChoice` gets an input from the user and never does anything with it. Then when `useValue` gets called, it gets *another* user input and uses that on the print the output.

Comment: def userChoice():
    print("Press 1 to send text message\n Press 2 to share file")
    action = int(input("Please what do you want to do ? "))
    return action


def useValue(choice):
    value=choice + 1
    print(value)

user_input = userChoice()
useValue(user_input)

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you are asking. If you need to add clarifying information to the original question, you can do that by editing the question rather than in the comments (code does not format very well in comments). If you have a different question, you might want to open a new question. Remember to accept an answer that resolves your question, and upvote those which you find useful.